# How to show operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely compact operators. In the text, the author gives the following example:

> **Example 1**: Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be positive constants and let
> $$
> M:=\left\{x(t)\in C[a,b]:|x(t)|<C_1\text{ and }|x'(t)|<C_2\right\}.\tag{1}
> $$
> Then $M$ is relatively compact.

I completely understand **Example 1**, it makes use of Arzela's theorem. Then the author gives the following example:

> **Example 2**: The operator
> $$
> Ax:=\int_0^tx(\tau)d\tau.\tag{2}
> $$
> on $C[0,1]$ is a compact operator (use the previous example).

My question is fairly straightforward: using **Example 1**, how is this operator compact on $C[0,1]$?

As of now I have the following two definitions of compact operators:

> **Definition 1**: A linear operator $A\colon X\to Y$ is called a *compact operator* if and only if for every bounded sequence $x_n\in X$ the sequence $Ax_n$ has a Cauchy subsequence.

> **Definition 2**: An linear operator $A\colon X\to Y$ is compact if and only if the image of the unit ball of $X$ is a relatively compact set in $Y$.

Just going off terminology, I would guess that **Definition 2** should be used to solve **Exercise 2**, but I'm not seeing it through all the way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take $M$ to be the image of the unit ball and use Example 1 to show that $M$ is relatively compact. You are then done by Definition 2.

Comment: Can you find a constant $C>0$ so that for any $x\in C[0,1]$ satisfying $\|x\|_{C[0,1]}\le 1$, and every $t\in [0,1]$,

 1. $|Ax(t)| < C$, and
 2. $|(Ax)'(t)| < C$?

If so, then you will have shown that the image of the unit ball in $C[0,1]$ is contained in the set $M$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz: Yes, thanks I see it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to notice that $|Ax|\leq \max_\limits{t\in[0,1]}x(t)$ (which comes immediately since $x$ is continous on a compact and the integral function is monotonic). Such maximum actually controlls also the derivative of $Ax$, thus if you take a set $M$ of functions of the form $Ax$ where $x\in B(0,1)$ you obtain a precompact space by example $1$ and with the second definition. By $B(0,1)$ I denoted the unit ball of center $0$ in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.